# DNS request using TCP using scapy

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, scapy

Wanted to  send a DNS request in TCP, and recieve its response. The response I receive from the namervers seems.. incomplete.

Below is the code I wrote for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket
from scapy.all import *

def main():
        ip = IP(dst="8.8.8.8")
        request = DNS(rd=1, qd=DNSQR(qname = "cnn.com", qtype="A")) # size = 25, hex = 0x19
        twoBytesRequestSize = "\x00\x19" #BIG ENDIAN
        completeRequest = str(request) + twoBytesRequestSize
        # Create TCP Packet with SYN
        SYN = ip/TCP(sport=RandNum(1024,65535), dport=53, flags="S", seq = 32)
        # Send the crafted packet, and get SYN ACK from the other end
        SYNACK = sr1(SYN)
        # We, the client need to send ACK for the server's SYN
        ACK = ip/TCP(sport=SYNACK.dport, dport=53, flags="A", seq=SYNACK.ack, ack = SYNACK.seq +1)
        send(ACK)

        # send the request, and
        DNSREQUEST = ip/TCP(sport=SYNACK.dport, dport=53, flags="PA", seq=SYNACK.ack, ack = SYNACK.seq +1) / completeRequest
        DNSREQUEST.show2()
        DNSREPLY = sr1(DNSREQUEST, timeout=3)

        DNSREPLY.show2()
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Here's what we sent,
DNSREQUEST.show2():

```
###[ IP ]###
  version   = 4
  ihl       = 5
  tos       = 0x0
  len       = 127
  id        = 1
  flags     =
  frag      = 0
  ttl       = 64
  proto     = tcp
  chksum    = 0xa7f8
  src       = 192.168.1.200
  dst       = 8.8.8.8
  \options   \
###[ TCP ]###
     sport     = 45597
     dport     = domain
     seq       = 33
     ack       = 3264934925
     dataofs   = 5
     reserved  = 0
     flags     = PA
     window    = 8192
     chksum    = 0xe104
     urgptr    = 0
     options   = []
###[ DNS ]###
        length    = 25127
        id        = 23672
        qr        = 0
        opcode    = 6
        aa        = 0
        tc        = 0
        rd        = 0
        ra        = 0
        z         = 0
        ad        = 1
        cd        = 1
        rcode     = ok
        qdcount   = 23672
        ancount   = 12336
        nscount   = 23672
        arcount   = 12337
        qd        = ''
        an        = ''
        ns        = ''
        ar        = ''
###[ Raw ]###
           load      = "\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x03cnn\\x03com\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x01'\x00\x19"
```

And we got,
Reply:

```
Received 51 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
###[ IP ]###
  version   = 4
  ihl       = 5
  tos       = 0x0
  len       = 40
  id        = 51159
  flags     =
  frag      = 0
  ttl       = 57
  proto     = tcp
  chksum    = 0xe778
  src       = 8.8.8.8
  dst       = 192.168.1.200
  \options   \
###[ TCP ]###
     sport     = domain
     dport     = 45597
     seq       = 3264934925
     ack       = 0
     dataofs   = 5
     reserved  = 0
     flags     = R
     window    = 0
     chksum    = 0x7465
     urgptr    = 0
     options   = []
###[ Padding ]###
        load      = '\x00\x00\x13\xa9\xa3\x11'
```

Not sure it is working though, or, that I am not extracting the DNS response right from. The DNS reply we got should have more stuff in it, no? I can't even tell whether this query succeeded - we sent more bytes than we received in reply:

```
(Pdb) len(DNSREQUEST)
127
(Pdb) len(DNSREPLY)
46
(Pdb)

(Pdb) DNSREPLY
<IP  version=4 ihl=5 tos=0x0 len=40 id=46137 flags= frag=0 ttl=58 proto=tcp chksum=0xfa16 src=8.8.8.8 dst=192.168.1.200 options=[] |<TCP  sport=domain dport=11225 seq=1761828349 ack=0 dataofs=5 reserved=0 flags=R window=0 chksum=0xea51 urgptr=0 |<Padding  load='\x00\x00\x813\x8d\xd2' |>>>
```

If it were a UDP query, the answer is evidently present in the reply packet.

How do I visualize a valid DNS response from the TCP response packet?

**Edit 1**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket
from scapy.all import *

def main():
        ip = IP(dst="8.8.8.8")
        request = DNS(rd=1, qd=DNSQR(qname = "cnn.com", qtype="A")) # size = 25, hex = 0x19
        # Create TCP Packet with SYN
        SYN = ip/TCP(sport=RandNum(1024,65535), dport=53, flags="S", seq = 32)
        # Send the crafted packet, and get SYN ACK from the other end
        SYNACK = sr1(SYN)
        # We, the client need to send ACK for the server's SYN
        ACK = ip/TCP(sport=SYNACK.dport, dport=53, flags="A", seq=SYNACK.ack, ack = SYNACK.seq +1)
        send(ACK)

        # send the request, and
        DNSREQUEST = ip/TCP(sport=SYNACK.dport, dport=53, flags="PA", seq=SYNACK.ack, ack = SYNACK.seq +1) / request

        _, answers = sr(DNSREQUEST, timeout=3, multi=1)
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

**Edit 2:**

Preventing RST as I learned from [this](https://www.fir3net.com/Programming/Python/how-to-build-a-tcp-connection-in-scapy.html) page:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP
```

I see the DNS server responding in my [ngrep](https://evuraan.info/screenshots/images/ngrep_response.png) when running the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from scapy.all import *

ip=IP(dst="8.8.8.8")

request = DNS(rd=1, qd=DNSQR(qname = "cnn.com", qtype="TXT")) #size = 27(dec) = 1b (hex)
twoBytesRequestSize = "\x00\x1b" #BIG ENDIAN
completeRequest = str(request) + twoBytesRequestSize

SYN=ip/TCP(sport=RandNum(1024,65535), dport=53, flags="S", seq=42)
SYNACK=sr1(SYN)

ACK=ip/TCP(sport=SYNACK.dport, dport=53, flags="A", seq=SYNACK.ack, ack=SYNACK.seq + 1)
send(ACK)

DNSRequest = ip/TCP(sport=SYNACK.dport, dport=53, flags="PA", seq=SYNACK.ack, ack=SYNACK.seq + 1) / completeRequest
#DNSReply = sr1(DNSRequest, timeout = 1)
DNSReply = sr1(DNSRequest, timeout = 1, multi=1)
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

However, I still don't see DNS related stuff in DNSReply:

```
(Pdb) DNSReply.show2()
###[ IP ]### 
  version   = 4
  ihl       = 5
  tos       = 0x0
  len       = 40
  id        = 36387
  flags     = 
  frag      = 0
  ttl       = 120
  proto     = tcp
  chksum    = 0xe22c
  src       = 8.8.8.8
  dst       = 192.168.1.200
  \options   \
###[ TCP ]### 
     sport     = domain
     dport     = 2466
     seq       = 3994942779
     ack       = 130
     dataofs   = 5
     reserved  = 0
     flags     = A
     window    = 28640
     chksum    = 0x77c1
     urgptr    = 0
     options   = []
###[ Padding ]### 
        load      = '\x00\x00^\x97\xf94'
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Using Scapy's latest release (2.4.0), you don't need to add the length at the beginning of the DNS layer, since it will be added automatically.

Your code is not working because you get a plain ACK packet (with no data) before getting the answer.

An option here is to use `sr([...], multi=1)`. You can try something like that in your code:

```
    answers, _ = sr(DNSREQUEST, timeout=3, multi=1)
    DNSREPLY = answers[DNS][0]
```

Also, as always when you play with TCP & Scapy, you need to make sure that your OS stack won't interfere with your packets (normally, it will reply with a reset packet to the syn+ack packet you receive). The usual way to do this is to use your firewall to prevent the syn+ack packet from reaching the OS stack.

Comment: Thank you Pierre. I am using scapy, 2.4.0 and changed the code as show in Edit 1 above. Seems like it still is returning blank: `(Pdb) answers
<Unanswered: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:0>
(Pdb) answers[TCP]
<TCP from Unanswered: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:0>`

Comment: Thank you Pierre, please Edit 2 above - I do see the server responding in my ngrep, however the answer seem to have no DNS Layer in it: `DNSReply[DNS]   
*** IndexError: Layer [DNS] not found`  What are we missing here? Thanks!